# Example on AES OCB encryption not working properly

Tags: python, encryption

So I am making a encryption program and was hoping to find some information on AES's OCB mode and the documentation luckily had a example with it only problem is that the example doesn't actually work as intended:

```
import json
from base64 import b64encode
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

header = b"header"
data = b"secret"
key = get_random_bytes(16)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_OCB)
cipher.update(header)
ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(data)

json_k = [ 'nonce', 'header', 'ciphertext', 'tag' ]
json_v = [ b64encode(x).decode('utf-8') for x in cipher.nonce, header,                                                                                                                                     
ciphertext, tag ]
result = json.dumps(dict(zip(json_k, json_v)))
print(result)
```

In the line where json_v is getting defined it tells me that "cipher.nonce" produces a Invalid Syntax error and I can understand why because it is defined nowhere **so I was hoping that someone here might have a look over this example and fix it into a working example so I can actually understand how I use nonce properly**

I will provide a link to the documentation where I found the example it's all the way at the bottom under OCB.

[Link to the documentation](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/modern.html)

Answer (score 3):

The SyntaxError has nothing to do with `cipher.nonce` being undefined. They're using Python 2 syntax in the list comprehension. You need parentheses when performing a list comprehension over a tuple literal in Python 3:

```
json_v = [b64encode(x).decode('utf-8') for x in (cipher.nonce, header, ciphertext, tag)]
```

Comment: Incidentally, the `except KeyError, ValueError` syntax on the decryption example is also incorrect. It should be `except (KeyError, ValueError)`. On Python 2, `except KeyError, ValueError` catches `KeyError` and assigns the exception object to `ValueError`, rather than catching `KeyError` and `ValueError`.